# Opencv giving a C++ exception error form my python code

Tags: python, opencv

While making a **barcode scanner** I am facing the issue with opencv. \

> My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar


video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)


while True:
    cap, frame = video.read()
    rot = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_180)

    decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(rot)
    for obj in decodedObjects:
        print("Product", obj.data)
        

    cv2.imshow("Frame", rot)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

> When I execute this code, it gives me an error.

```
cap, frame = video.read()
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

**All kinds of support will be appreciated.**

Comment: Whe I run this code, I get no error, it runs properly

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Thank you for replying, but when I still run this code, it gives the same error. I am using the latest opencv version i.e. **4.5.2.54**.  Is there any other way through which I can explain this problem in a better way?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk This code is working perfectly with my integrated webcam but when I switch to the external webcam it gives me this error.